# Saving symbology in GeoPackage with ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, symbology, geopackage

I'm working with a GeoPackage file containing polygons in ArcMap 10.6.2
I have hundreds of different classes symbolized one by one that I have stored in a LYR file.

It could be possible to save all this symbology inside the GeoPackage file as I can do with QGIS 3.4 (in style_layer table)?

It is not possible to read the GeoPackage symbology saved with QGIS from ArcMap. So, I'm trying to save this symbology in the GeoPackage with ArcMap.

Any other ideas or solutions?

Comment: ArcMap 10.6.1 was the last 10.6 release. ArcGIS and QGIS symbology are usually incompatible. Only a format like KML has styling included.

Comment: Yes, I'm  working with version 10.6.1 (sorry about typo mistake). I know that QGIS and ArcMap symbology are incompatible. QGIS 3.4 can save symbology in geopackage format (but only QGIS compatible)  so I would like to know if it is possible to do with arcmap. Thanks !